# How can i use a nested select statement like this select * from (select refer_id from b01)t;

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named 'a01' and 'b01'
in table 'b01' the table name of 'a01' is given and i want to access 'a01' table by the following subquery 
 **select * from (select refer_id from b01)t;**
but it is showing me only the refer_id of b01 not showing anything about the 'a01' table...
any suggestion is helpful.....

Comment: your query just says `select refer_id from b01` ... that is all you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use inner query if you want to get only a01 records

```
select * from a01 where refer_id in (select refer_id from b01);
```